# Appveyor seems to ignore infomational version

Tags: nuget-package, appveyor

I'm trying to get my NuGet package to be versioned by AssemblyInformationalVersion while keeping AssemblyVersion same. I use tag $version$ in my .nuspec.

However, if I build NuGet using appveyor, it keeps up using AssemblyVersion.

My `appveyor.yaml`:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
pull_requests:
  do_not_increment_build_number: true
configuration: Release
assembly_info:
   patch: true
   file: '**\AssemblyInfo.*'
   assembly_file_version: '{version}'
   assembly_informational_version: '{version}'
before_build:
   nuget restore
build:
   publish_nuget: true
   parallel: true
   verbosity: minimal
deploy:
   provider: NuGet
   api_key: <SKIPPED>
```

My `.nuspec` excerpt

```
<metadata>
 ....
    <version>$version$</version>
 ....
</metadata>
```

UPD: 
I checked that informational version set correctly to files:
[image: Informational version]

Also, I don't know if it related, but it seems to ignore my  `<files>` directive and put everything into `lib` instead of `analyzers\dotnet\cs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This often happens if `AssemblyInfo.*` file does not contain `AssemblyInformational` tag. In this case AppVeyor has nothing to patch.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it doesn't help.
Informational version does set correctly, but seems to ignored.

Comment: Forked your repo, created appveyor.yml from what you posted and all works OK. Also added  `publish_nuget_symbols: true` and `include_nuget_references: true` to looks it more like in your build and it still works OK: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/IlyaFinkelshteyn/hardcode-analyzer. Please try again and if this does not work, export you current config into YAML.

Comment: It's magic! I taken my YAML using "export config", pushed it into github and everything started working fine. 
But still &lt;files&gt; ignored (and so in your project)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have follow up here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610749/appveyor-nuget-analyser