# Appveyor nuget analyser

Tags: c#, nuget, roslyn-code-analysis, appveyor

I'm trying to invent good way to pack my Roslyn analyzer projects into NuGet.
It requires specific NuGet package structure with `.dll` put into `\analyzer\`, not `\lib\`.

For this to work, I have to call `nuget pack <name>.nuspec`, not `nuget pack <name>.csproj`. But if I use `nuspec`, than $version$ tag gets ignored.

Seems that my only option is to manually update version in `.nuspec` on every rebuild. What is correct and *right* way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is <name> the same and both .nuspec and .csproj are in the same folder?

Comment: <name> is same, files in same folder BEFORE compilation. (it's same project that you helped me before).

Comment: @ilyaf I secretly hope on help from you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way is:

1. Call nuget pack .nuspec from .csproj
2. Pass Version extracted from Assembly as parameters.
3. Make Appveyor update version on rebuild
4. Configure Appveyor to capture .nupkg`s to artifacts and push it.

See https://github.com/leotsarev/hardcode-analyzer as example

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. I don't like the idea of adding an after-build instruction to my csproj file (I don't want to build the nuget package every time I compile), so instead I configured an "after build script" in AppVeyor:

`nuget pack "yournuspecfile.nuspec" -Version %APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION%`

The nuspec contains a dummy `<version>` tag, the actual version is specified in the `nuget pack` command using the `%APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION%` environment variable which is [provided by AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/environment-variables/)